# Display Mesh On Top Of Another | Remove Overalapping | Render Order | Three.js

Tags: three.js, render, overlapping, 3d-rendering

I have 2 obj meshes.
They both have some common areas but not completely.

I displayed them both by adding them to screen ..
Just like a mesh on top of another.
But  the lower mesh overlaps the top mesh
But what I want to acheive is the lower mesh  should  always stay below without overlapping and giving the space to the  entire top mesh.

I went  through this fiddle..[Fiddle with renderorder](http://jsfiddle.net/rhomaysu/)

And I tried something with this like..

```
var objLoader1 = new OBJLoader2();
objLoader1.load('assets/object1.obj', (root) => {
           root.renderOrder = 0;
           scene.add(root);
       });
var objLoader2 = new OBJLoader2();
objLoader2.load('assets/object2.obj', (root) => {
           root.renderOrder = 1;
           scene.add(root);
      });
```

But I don't know for what reason the overlap still stays ..

I tried...

```
var objLoader1 = new OBJLoader2();
objLoader1.load('assets/object1.obj', (root) => {
           objLoader1.renderOrder = 0;
           scene.add(root);
       });
var objLoader2 = new OBJLoader2();
objLoader2.load('assets/object2.obj', (root) => {
           objLoader2.renderOrder = 1;
           scene.add(root);
      });
```

Then I tried going through this Fiddle .. [Another Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Horsetopus/33623mpv/)
But when I run in I get only the lower or the upper mesh .
But I want to see both without any overlaps..

```
 var layer1 = new Layer(camera);
 composer.addPass(layer1.renderPass);
 layer1.scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF));
 var objLoader1 = new OBJLoader2();
 objLoader1.load('assets/object1.obj', (root) => {
        layer1.scene.add(root);
  });
  var layer2 = new Layer(camera);
  composer.addPass(layer2.renderPass);
  layer2.scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF));
  var objLoader2 = new OBJLoader2();
  objLoader2.load('assets/object2.obj', (root) => {
        layer2.scene.add(root);
  });
```

I made the material depthTest to False 
But Nothing Helped..

Can anyone help me achieve what  I wanted ..
If anyone couldn't figure what I mean by overlapping see the image below..

[image: Overlapping of Meshes Image - Example]

And Thanks to anyone who took time and effort to go through and help me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [polygonOffset](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material.polygonOffset) to achieve your goal, which modifies the depth value right before a fragment is written to help move polygons off of eachother without visually changing the position:

```
material.polygonOffset = true;
material.polygonOffsetUnit = 1;
material.polygonOffsetFactor = 1;
```

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/5s8ey0ad/1/

Here is what the [OpenGL Docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPolygonOffset.xhtml) have to say about polygon offset:

> When GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL, GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE, or GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_POINT is enabled, each fragment's depth value will be offset after it is interpolated from the depth values of the appropriate vertices. The value of the offset is factor×DZ+r×units, where DZ is a measurement of the change in depth relative to the screen area of the polygon, and r is the smallest value that is guaranteed to produce a resolvable offset for a given implementation. The offset is added before the depth test is performed and before the value is written into the depth buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You're experiencing [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting), which is when two or more planes occupy the same space in the depthBuffer, so the renderer doesn't know which one to render on top of the other. Render order alone doesn't fix this because they're both still on the same plane, regardless of which one gets drawn first. You have a few options to resolve this:

1. Move one of the beams ever so slightly up in the y-axis. A tiny fraction would give one priority over the other, and this distance may not be noticeable to the eye.
2. I saw your fiddle, and you forgot to add `depthTest: false` to your material. However, this will cause issues when depth-testing the rest of the shape, since some white is on top of the red, but also some red is on top of the white. The approach in the fiddle works only when it's a simple plane, not more complex geometries.
3. You can use a boolean operation that removes one shape from the other, like [CSG](http://evanw.github.io/csg.js/).

I think you'd save yourself a lot of headache by using approach #1.

Comment: Thanks for the response..But 1.The beam example is just a case but I have to face the same issue with different geometries like a sphere and a cube & lot more  .obj geometries so I think moving wouldn't be good choice because I wanted both to stay close & not overlap to achieve the required geometry.. 2.I did try with doing....var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({side: THREE.DoubleSide,depthTest :false});.... But still only one geometry got displayed... And I think it can be done with completely three.js alone is anything wrong with the loading or calling it ..

Comment: Z-fighting can't be just fixed without a workaround. If you think it can be done, you should show or build a working fiddle that demonstrates exactly what you want, not simpler demos with just planes. It's not the loader's fault.